# value of decoded json

Tags: python

I try to get item from dict, which was decoded by json:

```
data = [ { 'a':'A', 'b':(2, 4), 'c':3 } ]
data_string = json.dumps(data)
decoded = json.loads(data_string)
decoded['c']
```

So it shows the next:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

I try to print the value of c on screen 
So I try to see 3 after decoded['c'] 
How can I do this ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your data is a list *containing* a dictionary

you can use `decoded[0]['c']` since the dictionary is the first element of the list

another possibility is that you should use `data = {u'a': u'A', u'c': 3, u'b': [2, 4]}` (no square brackets)

It really depends on whether you mean for data to be a list of dictionaries or just a dictionary

Answer (score 1):

the data you've encoded is a one element list.  Do you perhaps mean:

```
decoded[0]['c']
```

Answer (score 0):

`data` is a list, not a dict. Try:

```
data = { 'a':'A', 'b':(2, 4), 'c':3 }
data_string = json.dumps(data)
decoded = json.loads(data_string)
decoded['c']
```